# Bootstrap 4 grid with overlapping button on columns

Tags: button, bootstrap-4, grid

I'm trying to set up a website grid in bootstrap. To clearify the end results I want I added an image. [end results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvC0b.jpg)

- I have standard bootstrap navbar in place. (is ok for now)
- I want the columns to fill the complete height.
- I want the "read more" button to overlap the columns underneath eachother.
- The subtitle needs to be aligned to the left of the title. Now it's centered due to the whole div content is being centered.

**Column height issue**

So I have 2 columns side by side and 1 column underneath. I want it to fill up the height to 100%.
So let's say that the 2 columns side by side take up 80% of the height. (40% padding bottom and 40% top)
And the full width column to fill up the rest of the height. Say 10%/10% top/bottom padding.

However when I do this the height is more than the screen height and it's already out of the viewable area.

**Overlapping button**

As an extra headeache, I need 2 buttons that overlap 50% with the column underneath. I can't seem to get this to work.

The code I have in place now:

```css
body {
    font-family: Sofia-pro;
}

#header-block-left, #header-block-right {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40%;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
}

#page-scroll-anchor-grey {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#header-block-right {
    background-color: #dcdbd7;
}

#page-scroll-anchor-grey {
    background-color: #dcdbd7
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Code Atelier</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/png0dbx.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="style.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/Elements/Logo/logo-dark.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Merk Atelier <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Oplossingen</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div id="header-block-left">
                        <h1>Product A</h1>
                        <h6>Subtitel</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div id="header-block-right">
                        <h1>Product A</h1>
                        <h6>Subtitel</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="page-scroll-anchor-grey">
                        <h6>Scroll snel verder</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
        </div>
 


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `vh` unit to set the heights relative to the height of the screen.

You could set some `min-height`s on the nav/header and footer in order to ensure they hit a certain size and then switch the #main `height` to `max-height` to have it take up the rest of the vertical space on the screen.

```css
nav {
    height: 10vh;
    background: grey;
}

#main {
    height: 80vh;
}

#header-block-left {
    background: white;
}

#header-block-right {
    background: gray;
}

.btn {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

footer {
    height: 10vh;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/Elements/Logo/logo-dark.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Merk Atelier <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Oplossingen</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<section id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div id="header-block-left" class="header-block h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <h1>Product A</h1>
                <h6>Subtitel</h6>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block">Text</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div id="header-block-right" class="header-block h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <h1>Product A</h1>
                <h6>Subtitel</h6>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto d-block">Text</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <p class="m-0">Text in the footer</p>
</footer>
```